# Image texture recognition with python

Tags: python, image, textures, classification

I am looking for an algorithm/modules to identify and classify different types of soil in picture such as dry dirt, mud, oily earth and very liquid mud.

Any suggestion how to do this with python?

Comment: For a first cut you could try PCA with Grace Avery's application at https://github.com/graceavery/Eigenstyle.  She blogged about using this for classification of dresses and other clothing with images as input (http://blog.thehackerati.com/post/126701202241/eigenstyle).  Perhaps there is not as much variation in soil as there is in clothing, but maybe it could be enhanced with Pillow's ImageEnhance (http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageEnhance.html)

Comment: Thanks, will check it out.

Comment: There is an example of texture classification at http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_gabor.html and the Image Processing SciKit (Toolbox for SciPy) feature module has two functions for texture analysis (greycoprops and local_binary_pattern, see http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#greycoprops  and http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#local-binary-pattern).